# How can I get list Languages from NaturalLanguage

Tags: swift

I want to get a list of available languages for text translations. The text is unknown.

I created a simple project:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func LanguagesList () {
        let allLanguages = Locale.isoLanguageCodes
        let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        for languageCode in allLanguages {
            if let languageName = locale.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode) {
                print("\(languageCode): \(languageName)")
            }
        }
        let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
        recognizer.
        let textRecognitionLanguages = recognizer.availableRecognitionLanguages(for: .text)
        print(textRecognitionLanguages)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Languages list") {
                LanguagesList()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I tried to ask ChatGPT. It claims that this is how it should work (SDK 14, NaturalLanguage version 2.0). I updated the OS.

I have Xcode 14.3 includes Swift 5.8 and SDKs for iOS 16.4, iPadOS 16.4, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4, and macOS Ventura 13.3.

The compiler throws 2 errors:

**1. Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'text'**

**2. Value of type 'NLLanguageRecognizer' has no member 'availableRecognitionLanguages'**

Is there a way to get a list of available languages for text translations. The text is not known in advance?

Comment: This is why ChatGPT isn't allowed here. It gives bad code. The `NLLanguageRecognizer` class has never had an `availableRecognitionLanguages` member, at least according to the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of available languages for text translations. The text is not known in advance?
Is there a way to get a list of available languages for text translations. The text is not known in advance?

Comment: As @HangarRash said, `availableRecognitionLanguages` does not exist. For a full list of `NLLanguage`s, see the docs for the enum: [`NLLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguage).

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough how often ChatGPT entirely makes up APIs. Occasionally it is a useful tool. Equally often, it is an actively harmful tool that will send you in the wrong direction. I do not recommend it unless you already are an expert in the specific field you're asking about. @MrDeveloper, could you turn your comment into an answer? It matches what's asked here. (However,  Анатолий, are you sure you're asking what you really want? It's hard to know what you would do with this information at runtime. Do you just want to know for development purposes?)

Comment: @RobNapier thank you for your suggestion, I have turned my comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

(From my comment): As `@HangarRash` said, `availableRecognitionLanguages` does not exist. For a full list of `NLLanguage`s, see the docs for the enum: [`NLLanguage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguage). For many enums, especially ones that you create, there is a useful protocol for looping over all of the cases, which is exactly what you are trying to do above. This protocol, called [`CaseIterable`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-list-all-cases-in-an-enum-using-caseiterable), is not one that `NLLanguage` conforms to, but as [this Hacking with Swift article says](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-list-all-cases-in-an-enum-using-caseiterable), we can make it conform ourselves. Here is an example of adding this conformance:

```swift
extension NLLanguage: CaseIterable {
    public static var allCases: [NLLanguage] {
    [.amharic, .arabic, .armenian, .bengali, .bulgarian, .burmese, .catalan, .cherokee, .croatian, .czech, .danish, .dutch, .english, .finnish, .french, .georgian, .german, .greek, .gujarati, .hebrew, .hindi, .hungarian, .icelandic, .indonesian, .italian, .japanese, .kannada, .kazakh, .khmer, .korean, .lao, .malay, .malayalam, .marathi, .mongolian, .norwegian, .oriya, .persian, .polish, .portuguese, .punjabi, .romanian, .russian, .simplifiedChinese, .sinhalese, .slovak, .spanish, .swedish, .tamil, .telugu, .thai, .tibetan, .traditionalChinese, .turkish, .ukrainian, .urdu, .vietnamese, .undetermined]
    }
    
}
```

And then we can loop over each case like this:

```swift
print(NLLanguage.allCases)
//Prints each and every case
```

We have to declare this conformance ourselves, which also means we have to update it if Apple releases a new `NLLanguage`. Here are two examples, one with the code that you provided above, and one displaying a list (via `ForEach`) of all of the cases. First, for the code you provided above:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func LanguagesList() {
        for lang in NLLanguage.allCases {
            let locale = Locale(identifier: lang.rawValue)
            if let languageName = locale.localizedString(forIdentifier: lang.rawValue) {
                print("\(lang.rawValue): \(languageName)")
                        }
        }
        print(NLLanguage.allCases.map({ lang in
            lang.rawValue
        }))
        //Or, if you want to print the actual language names, use the following:
//        print(NLLanguage.allCases.map({ lang in
//            Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: lang.rawValue) ?? lang.rawValue
//        }))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Button("Languages list") {
                LanguagesList()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And next, a `ForEach`:

```swift
struct LanguagesListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(NLLanguage.allCases, id: \.self) { lang in
                Text(Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: lang.rawValue) ?? lang.rawValue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that it is not a good idea to use `id: \.self` in production, as if two values are the same, this can lead to undefined behavior. Above, I am using `Locale` because this displays the full `String` for the language - such as `"English"`, rather than the language identifier `"en"`. If you want to display the raw values, then just pass in `lang.rawValue`.

Comment: I copied your answer and got an error. Could you clarify what exactly is wrong?
Type 'NLLanguage' has no member 'allCases'

Comment: @Анатолий this error is what happens normally, without the extension at the top that makes this property available. Did you copy the top part of my answer, where I declared `extension NLLanguage: CaseIterable`? This is what makes that property available, and makes it so that the examples I provided below work.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that there is no solution. I previously used the list of languages ​​(6), I thought maybe there is a way to get the full list of supported languages, but I realised that this is redundant, As an option, I'll look at MLKit.